# RSS Feed parsing and display results in ListView then display body text upon click of the post

Tags: java, android, parsing, rss, feed

My Goal is optain a rss feed from a url of my choice, pull the data, list the different posts in a listview and upon click, Open up the post and display the body text of the post in a layout file.

So far currently i can pull the rss, display posts in list, and i have no action when post is clicked.

**New Objective:** Open new activity to display Post name and post body text from rss feed.

### AndroidRssReader.java

```
 public class AndroidRssReader extends ListActivity {

private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    try {
        //http://www.gov.hk/en/about/rss/govhkrss.data.xml
        URL rssUrl = new URL("http://feeds2.feedburner.com/greentechmedia-all-content.rss");
        SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
        RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
        myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
        InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
        myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

        myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (myRssFeed!=null)
    {
        TextView feedTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        TextView feedDescribtion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feeddescribtion);
        TextView feedPubdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
        TextView feedLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedlink);
        feedTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getTitle());
        feedDescribtion.setText(myRssFeed.getDescription());
        feedPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getPubdate());
        feedLink.setText(myRssFeed.getLink());

        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myRssFeed.getList());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

### rsslist.xml

```
<TextView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rowtext"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="25px"
android:textSize="10sp" />
```

### Main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/feedtitle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="@color/EnlightenBlue"
android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/feeddescribtion"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/feedpubdate"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:autoLink="web"
android:id="@+id/feedlink" />
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="No Data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I do have internet as a permission in my manifest.

Comment: What do you expect? You have no ListView or something. Btw you aren't making correct use of the Asynctask.

Comment: @Ahmad Yeah im trying to figure out how i go about including a listview for the content to display inside, How should the Asynctask be coded? thanks for the comment

Comment: @Ahmad I have updated the code and question to exactly what im trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you are ever running your async task. Also it looks like you are trying to declare your async task inside of the `onCreate()` method of your Activity. You'll probably need to move to to outside of `onCreate()` but still inside the Activity itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i appreciate it. Ill update the code with your recommendation, mind taken a 2nd look at it afterwards

Comment: Definitely. Just edit your question with the new code. I am help to try to help.

Comment: im having troubles getting eclipse to not populate a syntax error.

Comment: i have updated my code with some new code and layout stuff, now i can pull the rss feed posts, upon click them it doenst do anything. my goal now is to pull the body of the post to display in a new layout when i click a post. @FoamyGuy